# Selecting from a comma separated field

Tags: mysql, select

Say I have a `subscribers` table, that has a row for each user like this..

```
id name    subscribers
1  user1   user2,user3,user4
2  user2   user4,user5,user3
3  user3   user1,user6,user2    etc...
```

What I want to do is, run a select statement like this..

```
 SELECT subscribers from table where id = '1'
```

.. And then, limit how many subscribers to show me
i.e. If I limited it to 2, it would only `SELECT "user2,user3"` from `table.subscribers WHERE id=1`

I know I can limit it after selecting all with PHP but I don't want to run into performance problems, if there were millions of usernames in each column...

Also, is this the best structure to set up a `subscibe/follow` system.. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing multiple values in the same field.  This is bad!

**You need a second table, to represent subscriptions** - it would have a column `userid` and `subscriberuserid` (or something similar).

For every subscriber that a user has, there would be a record in this table with that user's userid (and the userid of their subscriber).

Then, you can limit to your hearts content:

```
SELECT subscribers.subscriberuserid
FROM subscribers
WHERE userid = 1
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: +1 for the fastest response with the correct normalisation answer, and the example of why it's the easiest and best solution

Comment: Thanx for that quick answer. So, does that also mean that each user will have multiple rows (a row for each subscriber) on that table?

Comment: That is correct.  One row per user in your user table, and one row per subscription in the subscription table.

Answer (score 0):

I think Many-To-Many relation would be more convenient, you could then easily limit your record numbers...