# Select value inside a comma separated string mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is something I have been thinking for hours and still cant get the answer.

So, I have this mysql table called 'orders'

```
+-----------------------------+
+ id | include                +
+-----------------------------+
+  1 | 4,7,9                  +
+  2 | 1,23,8                 +
+  3 | 11,6,3                 +                 
+  4 | 2,56,32,6              +
+-----------------------------+
```

I want to select a row when I have one number in the include column.

For example I have tried with this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `orders` WHERE `include` LIKE '%1%'
```

But the problem is it selects both rows 2 and 3 because number '11' contains '1'.

I need two querys: when the include table contains 'x', and when the include table does not contain 'x'.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You could expand your include Like to LIKE '%,1,%'

Comment: You should have two tables: A parent and a subtable with a JOIN, and then you select from the subtable.  The way you have it now, with comma-separated values for `include`, is only going to cause you sorrow and heartache down the road.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting from a comma separated field in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517379/selecting-from-a-comma-separated-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT *  FROM `orders` 
WHERE find_in_set(1, `include`) > 0
```

But generally it would be way better to change the table structure and store only one value in the column. It' the third rule of DB normalization.

Comment: +1 the third rule of DB normalization. The OP may need to read up on "one to many" and "many to many" relationships.